# Killing all instance of a specific program from the command line

Tags: command-line

Is there any way of killing all instances of a specific program with a command-line command?

Comment: Which OS? It's killall under *ix.

Comment: This question is too broad, unless you specify an OS or two you want to accomplish this on.

Answer (score 50):

#### In GNU/Linux, BSD, OS X, and other Unix-likes

```
killall program
```

#### In Windows

```
taskkill /IM program.exe
```

Comment: Careful with "other Unix-likes": On Solaris, `killall`, well, *kills all*: http://tehtable.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/note-to-self-solaris-linux/

Comment: Uses `/F` flag to forcefully kill.

Answer (score 4):

On many system you will find the commands `kill` and `killall`.

If you know the PID of the process then you can use `kill PID`

The first kills only one specific process. (Or rather, it sends a signal to it, e.g. the signal to terminate).  You can write a wrapper around that with ps and grep to kill all processes matching a name.

or, if installed, you could use `killall`

Beware though, not all killall commands do the same thing. On Solaris it kills **all** processes. I repeat, all. Not just those you wanted but each and every process you have the rights to kill will get killed. Make sure you check the manual page of your local system and or check if it is a link to killall5.

Comment: Nice. So is killall5 the nasty one or the one that kills the processes you wanted to?

Comment: `killall5` is the nasty one.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 7 (Vista?), I prefer `tskill processname` as you don't need to remember command line switches or write .exe at the end. eg:

`tskill chrome`

Will kill all chrome processes.

On windows XP I used `pskill` from the [pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) suite, which uses a similar syntax. Both these commands can also work on remote computers, if you have admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

In windows if you want to kill a process and  any child processes which were started by it you should use this command 
**Taskkill /im program.exe /t**

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 there is `taskkill`.

Answer (score 1):

for Windows, you can use
taskkill /im program_name
use taskkill /im program_name /f for more problematic programs
Use ProcessExplorer if you want a GUI alternative for Taskmanager

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the command is either [`pkill`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pkill.htm) or [`killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall). `pkill` is generally recommended, since on some systems, `killall` will actually *kill all processes*.

Comment: dis ~ # killall
    Usage: killall [OPTION]... [--] NAME...
           killall -l, --list
           killall -V, --version

      -e,--exact          require exact match for very long names
      -I,--ignore-case    case insensitive process name match
    ...

Comment: @Brendan Long: It is not an urban legend. On some SYS V systems `killall` actually kills all. That is not necessary a bad thing, but if you are not expecting it to behave differently on a different system then you might get an *educational moment*.